# correct flag to pass directory to g++ to include files

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc, g++

I have compiled gcc 5.3.0 from source on an aws.ami linux to learn more about the entire development compiling chain. I have searched a number of threads for several hours and have not found the right combination to understand exactly what is going on.

Looking in the .configure --help, I set the flag `--includedir=/home/mybin/include` and compiled the programs with no errors, using all the flags under `Fine tuning of the installation directories:`

When I compile a program passing `g++ -v test.cc` I see that by default the compiler is looking in

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/include
/usr/local/include
/home/mybin/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/include-fixed
/usr/include
End of search list.
```

for include programs such as `map & iostream` etc.

Q1: why doesn't the -v output show the `--includedir` in the search. I note it does however look there for `#include` programs.

Q2: I note that when the `make install` happened it did not copy the files from the compile tmp directory `/home/tmp/gcc-5.3.0/libstdc++-v3/include/std/....` to the `--includedir`. Is there a flag I have missed to get it to dump these files into that dir?

Q3: Also using the `--help` output I have set `CPPFLAGS="-I/home/anotherBin"` to test if it will scan this dir for other include files. However it does not seem to work.
So I tried each of the following with no success, what is the correct flag to set?

```
LDFLAGS="-L/home/anotherBin"     
        linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a               nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS="-l/home/anotherBin"
           libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have (understandably) misunderstood the function of the `--includedir` parameter of
`./configure`. This is a standard parameter of GNU autotools `./configure` scripts,
not just GCC's. The same if true for all the other `./configure` options under
the heading `Fine tuning of the installation directories`. They are boilerplate. 
The `--includedir` parameter specifies a non-default directory in which to install the
header files that contain the APIs of a library or libraries that are installed
by the script. Thus e.g. if you made an autotools package for a library
`libfoobar` that you had written, and I decided to install the package with

```
./configure --includedir=/usr/local/include/foobar --libdir=/usr/local/lib/foobar
```

then when I compiled and linked a program using `libfoobar`:

**main.c**

```
#include <foobar.h>

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

I would have to do it like:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include/foobar -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -o prog main.o -L/usr/local/lib/foobar -lfoobar
```

GCC is not a library that you link with your programs. You don't
`#include` any such thing as "the GCC API" in your source code. `--includedir`
is not relevant.

In the case of your question `Q3` you are also confused about the function of the `./configure` variable,
`CPPFLAGS`. This variable and its fellows (`CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, etc.) affects
*the behaviour of the compiler you already have when it is
building your new GCC*. They have no effect on the behaviour of the new compiler that you build.

In the typical installation with C and C++ (leaving aside the other supported languages), 
GCC comprises various cooperating tools for compiling, assembling and linking programs in
those languages plus implementations of the Standard libraries of
those languages. The installed locations of the tools, the binaries of the
Standard libraries and the header files of the Standard libraries are all primarily
controlled by the (specified or default) `--prefix` configure option, whereby a standard relationship
is maintained between all of these installed locations.

Do not depend on `./configure help` to install GCC. Start at the GCC Wiki,
[Installing GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC). Read that page carefully and
follow the links as you find necessary, including [Installing GCC: Configuration](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html).
I refer you especially to these words on that page:

> Options specification
>
> Use options to override several configure time options for GCC. A list of supported options follows; 
>   **‘configure --help’ may list other options, but those not listed below may not work and should not normally be used**.

(My emphasis)